# How to fix "WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_[“Cordova”]" in Ionic geolocation plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

## What I tried

I installed to Ionic **geolocation plugin** and launch **navigator plugin** and I get the below error when I use them

## Error

```
    WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_[“Cordova”]
    navme(address){
        this.launchNavigator.navigate(address);
    }
```

**Any ideas how to fix this?**